# How to use fgetcsv in PHP?

Tags: php, csv

I have been given a task and I have to read data from a csv file in PHP. I read up how to use it and got some good results but I am having trouble utilising the data that I get. The output of my code in plain text is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9 carat gold
    [1] => 11.87
)
Array
(
    [0] => 18 carat gold
    [1] => 23.73
)
Array
(
    [0] => Silver
    [1] => 0.49
)
Array
(
    [0] => Platinum
    [1] => 27.52
)
```

And the csv file is:

```
9 carat gold,11.87
18 carat gold,23.73
Silver,0.49
Platinum,27.52
```

I need to store the arrays somehow that I can use the data and then present it in a html table.

Comment: That looks pretty good, you can now use that array to display your values like you want

Comment: And what do you need? `fgetcsv` recovers data form csv file in an array

Comment: I need to be able to use that data, if I store this output in a variable, how will I use it?

Comment: I think you're pretty new to php, i'll explain in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Whith that data, why don't you present it in a foreach loop?

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
    </tr>
<?php    
foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row[0] . '</td>' . $row[1] . '</td></tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wel, i think your problem is you are pretty new to php, so i'll try to explain with an example:

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        //You have your data in the $data variable
        print_r($data);
        /* This will display for the first iteration
               Array
               (
                  [0] => 9 carat gold
                  [1] => 11.87
               )
        */
        echo "Name:" . $data[0] . " -> Value:" . $data[1]; //This displays: Name:9 carat gold -> Value: 11.87
     }
 }
```

I don't know what do you want so i hope it gives you an idea on how to use arrays and to store in a variable.

If you need anything else just tell me

Comment: You're right, PHP is new to me. Can you please explain how I can use the other iterations and also please can you explain what the "1000" does in the fgetcsv function?

Comment: The 1000 is the length of bytes you want to read, you can check the parameters here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php